# Excel SQL Query error: Details: "Microsoft SQL: Incorrect syntax near '='. Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ']) in Source'."

Tags: sql, excel, t-sql

I have four queries I created months ago with this code that execute fine. I am creating a new query, copying and pasting an old query and only changing the table reference from the database. I can't see any un-closed quotes and am baffled as to why this T-SQL code works in the old queries, but not in the new one I am creating. I've even tried copying and pasting an exact query that is already working and I'm still getting the error. Do you have any idea what the problem could be?

```
let
    Source = Sql.Database("Delta", "enteliwebDB", [Query="SELECT TOP 100 percent        #(lf)ts AS 'Timestamp', value#(lf)FROM [enteliwebDB].[dbo].[UASTP_150000_TL63]#(lf)where ts between dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0 ,getdate())-31, 0) #(lf)and #(lf)dateadd(day,datediff(day, 0 ,getdate()), 0)"])
in
    Source
```

Comment: What language is this written in? It sounds like your `])` is making it up to your sql server.

Comment: It's a T-SQL query from Excel. As you can see all the quotes are closed.

Comment: What I mean to say here is that I'm not familiar with this syntax (`Let` and `In`). Is this power query?  "Excel" is pretty broad and there are at least two other native ways in excel to query sql server, plus an endless of ways outside of excel to connect the excel and sql server.

Comment: not tsql problem

Comment: It is a power Query in Excel 2016.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside SQL query you have line feed **#(lf)**. Remove all **#(lf)** and it should work.

```
let
 Source = Sql.Database("Delta", "enteliwebDB", [Query="SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT ts AS 'Timestamp', value FROM [enteliwebDB].[dbo].[UASTP_150000_TL63] WHERE ts BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()) - 31, 0) AND DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0)"])

in
 Source
```